# Strange Error with OmniAuth, AWS S3 and omniauth-stocktwits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, omniauth, stocktwits

I have a rails app using omniauth for user authentication with facebook. twitter and google. I've add one more provider StockTwits, with gem omniauth-stocktwits. And now my application cant' start because of error:

```
/home/vladimir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@ea/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant OmniAuth::Strategies::Stocktwits (NameError)
```

I cant understand what problem is... Why aws s3 raises error for omniauth? And What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The constant should be `StockTwits`, not `Stocktwits`. Are you calling it without the capital T anywhere?

Otherwise could you give me more information on how you're requiring and initializing omniauth-stocktwits, and what the rest of the stack trace from your error looks like, so I can try reproducing it?

Also Google is showing a lot of unrelated `const_missing` errors bubbling up through the AWS-S3 gem, so it's possible this is completely unrelated to AWS.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for help! This problem gone away after I've upgraded some other gems, like devise. So, I really dont' know what is was :( But anyway thank for help!